# OpenCV + Android - face recognition not working

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I have been implemented this project: https://github.com/yaylas/AndroidFaceRecognizer into Android Studio. I included OpenCV using tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTw_GIQNbD8 (this is static initialization). Moreover, I set in Android Studio settings proper NDK location. 
Problem is that, if I add this Class:

```
package com.yaylas.sytech.facerecognizer;

import java.util.Vector;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class DetectionBasedTracker
{
    public DetectionBasedTracker(String cascadeName, int minFaceSize, boolean isFaceDetector) {
        mNativeObj = nativeCreateObject(cascadeName, minFaceSize, isFaceDetector);
    }

    public long getNativeObj(){
        return mNativeObj;
    }

    public void setMinFaceSize(int size) {
        nativeSetFaceSize(mNativeObj, size);
    }

    public void detect(Mat imageGray, MatOfRect faces) {
        nativeDetect(mNativeObj, imageGray.getNativeObjAddr(), faces.getNativeObjAddr());
    }

    public void release() {
        nativeDestroyObject(mNativeObj);
        mNativeObj = 0;
    }
    public static Vector<Mat> imageVector = new Vector<Mat>();
    public static void addElement(Mat m){
        imageVector.add(m);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------- elementAdded: "+imageVector.size());
    }

    public static long getElementAt(int index){
        if(index >= imageVector.size() || index < 0){
            return 0;
        }

        System.out.println("-------------------------***** get element: "+imageVector.size()+"  index: "+index);
        return imageVector.elementAt(index).getNativeObjAddr();
    }

    public static int getImageCount(){
        return imageVector.size();
    }


    private long mNativeObj = 0;

    private static native long nativeCreateObject(String cascadeName, int minFaceSize, boolean faceDetection);
    private static native void nativeDestroyObject(long thiz);
    private static native void nativeStart(long thiz);
    private static native void nativeStop(long thiz);
    private static native void nativeSetFaceSize(long thiz, int size);
    private static native void nativeDetect(long thiz, long inputImage, long faces);

}
```

An error is returned:

> Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function

I tried everything, but the error still is there. I would like to ask, where can be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several reasons why the runtime might not be able to resolve the JNI function. Test these hypotheses:

- The native code library didn't get bundled into your APK. Look inside the APK for it.
- The native code library is in the wrong directory of the APK. Again, look and see.
- The Java class got mangled by ProGuard so the names no longer match with the native library. Try turning off ProGuard. It should be off for debug builds.
- If your native code library is compiled for ARM but you're running in an x86 based Android emulator (or vice versa), it won't be able to load that library.
- Think of more hypotheses, then test them.

The page http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html has lots of info about OpenCV on Android, including links to tutorials.

Comment: Maybe can I find metods / tutorial to integrate JNI funcion in NDK OpenCV nature? I try these points and still my program doesn't working...

Comment: @Pitter I added a link to info on OpenCV on Android. That page links to dinner tutorials.